# Error message "cannot take that action right now" when system upgrade

Tags: magento2, admin, upgrade, magento-2.0

I installed Magento 2 on Ubuntu 14.04, and tried to examine whether anything I need to update in Magento system.

I enter "Web Setup Wizard" from admin panel, but it shows the error message at the first step.

> "Sorry, we can't take that action right now."

I have tried to find the solution in the official document, but nothing is found.

[image]

Comment: Thank everyone for answering my question. At the last, I still can't find out the solution. So I re-install my VM OS and Magento2.
Therefore, these new answers below I can't test them working or not.
If someone get solution from this post, please let the user (who supplies the answer) know.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same problem with my install. Resolved it by entering the Public / Private Access Keys (in the Web Setup Wizard's System Config, 'Magento Marketplace').

You can get these when you log into your account on magento.com - Click on 'Connect' tab at top, then click on 'Developers' button to reveal 'Secure Keys' link. Click on it to manage / create keys.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html

Comment: @Lenny When I enter my keys in windows xampp Magento2 installation I get SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Answer (score 2):

The error message comes from `setup/view/magento/setup/select-version.phtml` and is displayed if the value of the variable `upgradeProcessed` is `false`.
The variable is set in `setup/pub/magento/setup/select-version.js`.
Initially this is set to `false` and it is set to true if there is a success response from the url `index.php/select-version/systemPackage`.
This url is mapped to `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/SelectVersion.php` and `systemPackageAction`.
So I guess something goes wrong in here.
I have no idea what, but this is a great place to start debugging.

Comment: I got the reponse - {error: "System package not found", responseType: "error"} from success calback of $http.get('index.php/select-version/systemPackage', {'responseType': 'json'})

Comment: the error message comes from here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/SystemPackage.php#L68

Comment: It seems that my $systemPackageInfo value is false, but I still don't know why... By the way, my $systemPackages value is [magento/product-community-edition]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the problem is caused by the fact that you're not authenticated.

But sometimes, it's caused by the fact that you installed Magento 2 by cloning the GitHub repository.

In that case, you cannot use the Web Setup Wizard and have to run the following commands:

```
git pull origin
composer update
```

More details can be found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/were-sorry.html